# Rcpp returns the same matrix

Tags: r, rcpp

My Rcpp function returns the same result. Into this function i change some **studyClones** numbers, but when i take result, i have identical matrix studyClones. **What I do wrong?**

Rcpp code:

```
  NumericMatrix myFunction(NumericMatrix study, NumericMatrix numMatrix, double coef){
  int ind = 0;
  int sizeImage = study.rows();
  NumericVector randomNumbers;
  for(int i=0; i<numMatrix.rows(); i++){
    for(int j=ind; j<(numMatrix(i,0)+ind); j++){
      randomNumbers = sample(sizeImage, ceil(numMatrix(i,0)*coef), false);
      for(int k=0; k<randomNumbers.length(); k++){
        if(study(randomNumbers[k],j)==1){
          study[randomNumbers[k],j] = 0;
        }else{
          study[randomNumbers[k],j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    ind += numMatrix(i,0);
  }
 return study;
}
```

R code:

```
result <- myFunction(studyMatrix, numericMatrix, coefficienM)
all(result==studyMatrix)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. We don't know what to put into the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did wrong it that you missed that `study` is (roughly) a pointer to the original R data. when you modify `study` at C++ level you modify the original matrix not a copy. Thus  the R object `studyMatrix` is modified in place and you also return it. So basically `result` and `studyMatrix` are both the same original object modified in place in memory. Thus they are equal.

Try this code to understand:

```
void f(NumericMatrix M)
{
  M(0,0) = 0;
  return;
}
```

Then in R

```
m = matrix(1, 2,2)
m
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    1
#> [2,]    1    1
f(m)
m
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    0    1
#> [2,]    1    1
```

To fix your issue you can use `clone`

```
NumericMatrix f(NumericMatrix M)
{
  NumericMatrix MM = clone(M);
  MM(0,0) = 0;
  return MM;
}
```

Comment: Oh, i understand! Thank you so much!
But how can i write Rcpp function which will be to change result, but *study" will unchanged?